# How to control light bulbs with Raspberry Pi - Requirements

Tags: raspberry-pi

I can control LED using the raspberry pi. I was wondering how to control house light bulbs with raspberry pi. I mean what are requirements?

Comment: depends on their power and voltage requirements

Comment: Thank you for the reply @mangusta, the voltage is 220v, I want to control them remotely. I'm wondering how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code would be the same as for an LED, but you would need to switch a relay instead of the light itself.  
[image: Solid State Relay]  
http://www.newark.com/productimages/standard/en_US/4634348.jpg

Since the Raspberry Pi is not equipped to handle that much power, the relay is used because it can be switched on and off by 5v or 3.3v on one side, but actually handle your 220v on the side with the light.

---

***The Voltage on the high side of this circuit is dangerous, and can cause severe injury or death***  I *strongly suggest* you take all possible precautions and use **Personal Protective Equipment**.

---

If you are *not comfortable* working so directly with electricity, there are **ready made options** which are **much safer**, but generally cost more. You could check out products similar to this one: http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/PowerSwitchTail240vackit.aspx